# Error when passing argument Windows 10 manage-bde

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I am trying to stop BitLocker from running the recovery process at each startup, following advice given [here](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-9570-BitLocker-asks-for-recovery-key-after-dual-boot/td-p/6240947) (I don't have the same computer as the question):

```powershell
# Get TPM ID to use in next command:
  Manage-Bde -Protectors -Get C:

# I don't understand why it isn't getting the argument:
  Manage-Bde -Protectors -Delete C: -ID {XXXXX}

    ERROR: Parameter "-ID" requires an argument.

  Manage-Bde -Protectors -Add C: -TPM
```

Why is it not receiving the argument and is this the proper method for stopping BitLocker Recovery at each startup?

Answer (score 0):

Powershell requires quotes around the ID:

```powershell
Manage-Bde -Protectors -Delete C: -ID '{XXXXX}'
```